# Order matters database item

Tags: custom-field, schema, order

Trying to setup a database where it has a table with a bunch of devices, but when displaying the devices order matters. I would need to be able to **insert/delete** devices in **any part of the chain**. We may have to end up adding Device X between Device C and Device A; not necessarily after Device Z.

Essentially a **linkedlist** of devices.

device-pool table

**id** | **device_id** | **next_device**

this would easily work, considering you would only need to know the **start_device** which is stored separately. My question is, is it possible to do this with sales force?

Another idea would be

device-pool table

**id** | **device_id** | **device_order** | **pool_id**

**devider_order** would be a multiple of 10. -1 to insert device behind it, +1 ahead of it.

Any other ideas / how-to execute either of these ideas?

**solution**

We ended up not using the order list, or implement this feature for that matter. Although, I did get part way through the problem. What I did was assign a field next (points to the next object) and then have a field position. There's another field which ties it to the container (e.g, the pool). Created a custom trigger. Field position was 10,000 if next was null. Upon inserting a new object, it would grab the next id, find who previously points to it (if NULL this is okay), and do (Next_Pos - Pointer_Pos) / 2 for the position numeric. The assign Next to go to the new object (after insert), and voila! Now all you have to do is order by position and you're done!

Comment: I think the linked list option is not going work very well.  Your device_order idea will be a better fit for Salesforce.

Comment: Is there just one pool of devices or is each pool related to some other object?

Comment: Multiple pool of devices. Each device is physically next to each other, which is their relationship. Each pool is tied to another object (fiber_strand).

Comment: I thought I'd figured out a clever way to do this with a master-detail relationship, a count formula on the parent, a formula on the child to get the count, and a default value device order based on the count.  Alas, default value formulas can't reference other fields.  I think this will have to be done by way of a trigger.  You'll probably want a Visualforce page to let you rearrange the device order too.

Comment: In case you're still curious, I believe I'll be going that route Jagular. I'll update the main thread when I find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up not using the order list, or implement this feature for that matter. Although, I did get part way through the problem. What I did was assign a field next (points to the next object) and then have a field position. There's another field which ties it to the container (e.g, the pool). Created a custom trigger. Field position was 10,000 if next was null. Upon inserting a new object, it would grab the next id, find who previously points to it (if NULL this is okay), and do (Next_Pos - Pointer_Pos) / 2 for the position numeric. The assign Next to go to the new object (after insert), and voila! Now all you have to do is order by position and you're done!

Comment: Could you possibly share some code regarding this implementation? I'm doing the same right now.

Answer (score 0):

The unique ID's in the system end up incrementing, so you could always do a query like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Pool_Table__c WHERE Id > 'YOUR LAST ID' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

That should get you the next item in the list (if you just want them ordered by creation date).

Comment: Fortunately this would work as long as we didn't add any new devices to the middle of our chain; unfortunately for us, we do not know where the new device will be located. Thanks for the reply though, and I edited the main post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a problem - a lookup relationship to the same object type is fine.
You'd just need to make sure you updated all your next device id's on insert and delete.

One other thing I've seen is a sort key that just appends - your sort key would start out like this: device 1 sort key: 1, device 2 sort key: 2 etc...

On insert between device 1 and device 2, you'd append to device 1 and make a device 1.1 and between that a device 1.1.1 etc...

Just an idea, but I've seen it work before.